# Swift: Use property observer to get value from view

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom UIView (called GridView) that I initialize and then add to a ViewController (DetailViewController). GridView contains an Int property called numbers and I would like to know in DetailViewController when that property changes. Is it possible to use a property observer to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift provides you specific hooks, e.g. `didSet` which you can use for notifications when a property changes:

```
var x : Int { didSet { callAMethod() } }
```

You can then combine this with any other technique, e.g. delegation, callbacks, `NSNotificationCenter` and so on.